# gradlew connectedCheck does not generate coverage report

Tags: gradle, android-testing, gradlew

Why gradlew connectedCheck does not generate instrumental or UI test coverage reports? It does generate report but does not show any coverage. Is there an actual way to **get the coverage from the instrumental and UI tests**? I did not find any reference in official android testing guides/documentation.